How to modify Android13 PhotoPicker exit animation?
Here is the code.
ActivityResultLauncher<PickVisualMediaRequest> pickMedia = /**...**/

ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
        makeCustomAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

pickMedia.launch(new PickVisualMediaRequest.Builder()
                        .setMediaType(type)
                        .build(),options);

By setting CustomAnimation, I found that the slide_in animation can play normally, but the slide_out animation never plays and always defaults to the PhotoPicker's default animation. I have extensively searched for relevant information and have not found a direct way to modify PhotoPicker's exit animation. Because PhotoPicker is a new system component introduced in Android 13, I cannot directly inherit or modify its code. Therefore, I am reaching out to inquire if anyone knows how to correctly modify its exit animation?
